# Switch System Controls

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

What are the system controls referenced in the keyboard shortcut section of ubuntu 20 lts. There is two options to switch them directly and to switch them using a quick menu with two settings:

1. Windows
2. Top Bar

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release. Ubuntu has the more common *year.month* products (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS like your tag) but also *year* format products (eg. Ubuntu Core 20 which has a 10 year supported life so LTS isn't usually mentioned) which differ.  The `apt` and `dpkg` commands exist only in the *yy.mm* products; so details matter.  You've used both, but given they are different products being precise with details matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press the default keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+TAB you will have the option of "Top Bar" When you choose it, You can acces the "Top Bar" with keyboard controls without using mouse.

[image]

[image]